# CWM Recovery can't see external SD card, need to install a rom from ext SD

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking

Phone is a SGH-I747M. Was rooted. Tried to put a custom rom on it. Something happened. Now it loads to CWM-Recovery v5.5.0.4. I can't view the files on the SD Card. I have tried mounting the card from the menu. Still nothing. Please help. I think I can save this phone, but I just don't know how.

Comment: This situation can occur if you accidentally flash recovery to /boot, probably best to return to stock with ODIN/Kies and start over.

Comment: @acejavelin Odin doesn't recognize it when it's in CWM-recovery mode

Comment: Odin is only used with Download Mode.  Put it in Download Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Procedure:

- Make sure latest Samsung USB drivers are installed on your PC.
- Download [Odin v3.07](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiE1LXi68_LAhXEkQ8KHdCGDUYQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandroidhost.org%2FsOYpV&usg=AFQjCNGdxVNKRowCz3Ejim5T6VINEmqrbQ&sig2=NIkJLeQS83ZRNv4kKYN47g) on your PC.(Some SAMSUNG devices require [Odin v3.04](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXsvvJ68_LAhWEDw8KHaQfBogQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fattachment.php%3Fattachmentid%3D1148059&usg=AFQjCNEyctaWfRq2g4jVZ1zD_mjx3APNfg&sig2=2CzfCDjXBTYprfKFgjmFHA)).
- Download Recovery.tar, [download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1p-7ya9G3bBLW9wV2YwR0IwaVk/view?usp=sharing). This link Provides CWM Recovery.

Follow the Steps:

1. Run Odin v3.07 on your PC as an administrator.
2. Switch off your device, go to download mode (volume down + home screen button+ power button), then press volume up to continue and connect to your PC.
3. When Odin recognize your device, click PDA option(*Do not touch any other options*) and navigate to the recovery.tar file where you have downloaded it.
4. Select recovery file and hit START.

The flashing process will complete and Odin will show a PASS button with green background, your device will be rebooted.
After flashing the stock recovery file your phone should boot normally without any problem.

Now before you flash a new ROM –

- Make sure you have enabled USB  Debugging on your device
- Make sure you have latest Samsung USB drivers installed on your PC
- Wipe cache partition and wipe data/factory reset before you flash a ROM

Above Procedure is Adapted version. [Original Work.](http://www.kickiteasy.com/unbrick-samsung-android-phone/)

And if you want Original Samsung Firmware. 
Download Kies from Samsung Website which can put Samsung Firmware on your phone. [See This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1XV453_jWk).

Comment: Nicely done, a *significantly* better answer than your first revision, and probably the correct one. I will upvote it!